# Does Harrier's kick do more damage than others?

Tags: lawbreakers

LawBreakers introduced a new character with its release named Harrier. The character is extremely good fun, but there's something special compared to the other characters. Harrier's kick (melee in this game) uses both feet, and it almost feels like it does more damage.

Is this true? Does Harrier's double-kick do more damage than the other players who only kick with one foot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing in Sandbox mode with damage numbers turned on, it appears that yes, Harrier's kick deals extra damage. The numbers move and disappear very quick, but it appears that normal kicks do 75 damage, whereas Harrier's kick does 75 + 60, for a total of 135 damage.